# Dynamic event template in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there any way to dynamically change event template in FullCalendar?

**Update.** What I want is to specify new event html (e. g. in eventRender callback) and make FullCalendar to use it for my event rendering. Something like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  var template = '<div class="customEvent"></div>';
  return $.parse(template);
}
```

Tried the sample above - didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what do you refer as "event template". Can you explain a bit more or add screenshots of what you need? [ps] I see now that you removed the explanation in an edit... it's better with it...

Comment: @brasofilo, I'm not sure which code would help here. I'm just looking for a way to replace the html that is used to display events

Comment: I can't visualize exactly what you're asking. Instead of `eventRender`, you want to add events afterwards, is this it?

Comment: @brasofilo, I am okay about eventRender. Theoretically it allows to change event html but I haven't found any sample of doing so

Comment: What does `$.parse` do? Is that a plugin of yours?

Comment: @brasofilo, it was my faulty way to parse html string with jQuery (should've used $('some template') instead

Comment: @brasofilo, I accepted Richard Hermanson's answer but gave the bounty to you. I think it would be fair

Comment: Glad I could help to bring up the solution, cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The eventRender callback function can modify element, **return a brand new DOM element that will be used for rendering instead**, or it can return false, which will prevent the event from being rendered at all.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/506/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        return $('<div>' + event.title + '</div>');
    },

    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2014-06-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-06-07',
            end: '2014-06-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2014-06-28'
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: In v4, instead of accepting `(event, element, view)`, eventRender accepts `(info)`. You can access the previous params with `info.event`, `info.el` and `info.view` respectively. Also, you need to return a node instead of a JQuery object. Instead of `return $('<div>' + event.title + '</div>')`, simply edit the element. `info.el.innerHTML = '<div>' + info.event.title + '</div>'`.

Answer (score 21):

You can add meta information on the event, like classes, and style accordingly:

```js
events: [{
    title: 'Blue Event',
    start: '2014-06-01',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
    class: 'blue main'
}]
```

And the CSS:

```js
.fc-event.blue {}
.fc-event.main {}
```

On `eventRender` insert the classes with

```js
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.addClass(event.class)
}
```

And append more content like:

```js
if (event.description) {
    element.find('.fc-event-inner')
        .append("<div class='desc'>" + event.description + "</div>");
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: { left: '', center: '', right: '' },
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            if (event.description) {
                element.find('.fc-event-inner')
                    .append("<div class='desc'>" + event.description) + "</div>";
            }               
            element.addClass(event.class)
        },
        events: [{
            title: 'Blue Event',
            start: '2014-06-01',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
            class: 'blue main'
        }, {
            title: 'More Blue',
            start: '2014-06-01',
            description: 'More lorem ipsum',
            class: 'blue main'
        }, {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-06-07',
            end: '2014-06-10',
            class: 'red main'
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00',
            class: 'blue main'
        }, {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00',
            class: 'blue main'
        }, {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00',
            class: 'red main'
        }, ],
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eaefb5;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.fc-event-time, .fc-event-title {
    padding: 0 1px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.fc-event.main {
    border: 5px solid #bbb;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px
}
.fc-event.red {
    background-color: #f85032;
}
.fc-event.red .fc-event-title {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 1.2em
}
.fc-event.blue {
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #87e0fd), color-stop(40%, #53cbf1), color-stop(100%, #05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0', GradientType=0);
}
.fc-event.blue .fc-event-title {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #EEE;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #300000;
}
.fc-event.blue .desc {
    font-size:.8em;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.3/fullcalendar.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.0.3/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was asking for. But you are appending to fc-event-inner instead of creating a new event ui from scratch.

Comment: Well Idsa, you provided one line of explanation, I assumed lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

Use the eventRender(callback) function to change the event template. Here is how you can add a tip to the event:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
   element.qtip({
      content: event.description
   });
}
```

With this function you can fully customize any detail of the event that is displayed including adding a complete new event template. For more details check out the documentation:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: while links can be useful, they can also become obsolete if they break. How about copying some of the important points here as well to reinforce your point?

Comment: Documentation on this topic is very vague. It doesn't have any example of changing the template and doesn't tell if there any limitates for template to keep it treated by FullCalendar as event (e. g. should I keep some classes for root element?)

Answer (score 1):

In Version v4 of FullCalendar the arguments have changed (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.append(document.createTextNode(info.event.title));
    return node;
}
```

If you want to prevent an event from rendering just *return false*

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may append new information like this

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
       element.find('.fc-title').append('<span class="yourCSS"></span> '); 
}
```